# React: can't change input with onChange

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, state, onchange

I'm building this screen to load an Employee's details when going to `/employees/:id.`

**What works**: inputs correctly display data coming from `employeeDetails` state using redux.

**What doesn't work**: inputs won't change using `onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}` (...or `handleChangeInput`

I tried using `defaultValue` for the inputs but they populate with the last record's data and not the current one. And that's material for another question...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import {listEmployeeDetails} from '../actions/employeeActions'

const EmployeeDetailsScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(employee.name)
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const employeeDetails = useSelector((state) => state.employeeDetails)
  const { employee } = employeeDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listEmployeeDetails(match.params.id))
    
  }, [dispatch, match]) 

  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
  setName(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="input-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Employee Name</label>
         <input type="text" name='name' id='empName' value={employee.name} onChange={handleChangeInput} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

This is the action used, pulling data from a postgres database:

```
export const listEmployeeDetails = (id) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/employees/${id}`)

    dispatch({
      type: EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_SUCCESS, 
      payload: data.data.employees
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: EMPLEADO_DETAIL_FAIL,
      payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
  }
}
```

This is the reducer used:

```
export const employeeDetailsReducer = (state = {employee: {}}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, employee: {} }
    case EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, employee: action.payload }
    case EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Is `[name, setName]` not referring to the same `state` coming from `employeeDetails`?

Answer (score 2):

`handleChangeInput` is changing the `name` state, but the `value` of your `input` is pointing to `employee.name`, which is completely different.
Try to change the `value` of your `input` to `name`

Comment: But then the input would be blank... What I want is to first have it auto-filled with the employee's data but then also be able to change the input.

Comment: try moving `useSelector` above `useState`. Then initilize `useState` with `employeeDetails.employee.name`

Comment: Kinda... same as using `defaultValue`: on first time loading `name` state is undefined. Go back to list and select another user: it loads previous employee data. (example: 1. Alice loads no name, 2. Bob loads Alice, 3. Carl loads Bob... I don't know why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

As LaQuoc answer pointed out: `name` and `employee.name` were not the same. However `name` state remained undefined after loading.

The solution was both changing `value` to `{name}` as suggested while also adding a different `useEffect` to `setName` whenever `employee` renders:

```
const EmployeeDetailsScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const employeeDetails = useSelector((state) => state.employeeDetails)
  const { employee } = employeeDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listEmployeeDetails(match.params.id))
    
  }, [dispatch, match]) 

 useEffect(() => {
    setName(employee.name)
  }, [employee])

  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
  setName(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="input-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Employee Name</label>
         <input type="text" name='name' id='empName' value={name} onChange={handleChangeInput} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```